# Can't run Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS from external SSD

Tags: boot, ssd

Spent couple days on reading internet and trying to make it work...
Laptop - HP Probook
Desktop - Asus mb, RTX3080
SSD - M.2 nvme Kingston

Tried to install on laptop:

1. Try Ubuntu - removed existing esp and boot with GParted
2. Install -> Something else -> Allocated 200 mb as EFI, the rest for root ext4

Result after installation finished

1. Laptop just goest to infinite reboot when SSD connected. Just writes 'Reset system' on top left of the screen and reboot
2. PC - Loading with ubuntu sign, but right after login screen should appear - just black screen and nothing else.

I've tried to allocate partitions also before installing - result absolutely the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use the entire external SSD for Ubuntu why don't you use the automatic option that deletes the entire drive and makes all the necessary changes? Just select the external SSD for the installation and everything else will be taken care of by the installer. If you select **Something else**, besides creating the correct partitions manually, you have to instruct the installer to place the master boot record on the external SSD too. It's the last option at the bottom of the installer window. Did you do that?

Comment: I did not tried to select the whole SSD for that btw. The reason i go with Something else is that bug with grub location. Do you know if this bug is fixed in 23.10? Maybe i should try it?

Comment: 1396379 is the bug. Yes 23.10 fix by using a different install.

Comment: Ok, just tried automatic option for install on the whole SSD, but result is absolutely the same - HP goest to infinite 'Reset System', PC - to black screen. I chose the option to install graphic drivers from internet. What else can i try?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ HP systems have not been the easiest to work with, but most are able to evenually get it to work. With external install, are you able to boot it from UEFI one time boot menu, like you do with live installer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, kind of solved the problem by connecting to old laptop where system has loaded.

1. PC - installed nvidia driver
2. HP laptop by booting not from the SSD, but from EFI file. Not saying it's convenient, but at least it works...